# ¿Cómo creo una método para que me devuelva getResources().getColor(R.color.clrAzul)...?

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando mis primeras app en Android.

Mi duda es, ¿Cómo creo una método para que me devuelva `getResources().getColor(R.color.clrAzul)` y que tipo de dato debe devolver mi método para que Android lo acepte?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnAmarillo) {
        tvWordColor.setText("" + palabraRan(1));
        tvWordColor.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.clrAzul));// <-- AQUI
        /*Aqui me gustaria implementar algo similar al método palabraRan(int)
          Solo que no se como devolver este valor(color.xml) para que android lo "lea" */
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tendrás que crear un método que nos devuelva un entero.
Más información en [la documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).

> Cuando se compila tu aplicación, **aapt** genera la clase **R**, que contiene ID de recurso de todos los recursos de tu directorio res/...y para cada recurso de ese tipo hay un valor **entero estático** (por ejemplo, R.drawable.icon).

---

Un ejemplo de como podrías implementarlo en un método.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    int colorAzul = R.color.azul;
    TextView textView;

    public int getColorAzul(int color) {
        int miColor = getResources().getColor(color);
        return miColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.button:
                textView.setText("Mi texto ha cambiado");
                textView.setTextColor(getColorAzul(colorAzul));
        }

    }
}
```

**Resultado del antes y después de pulsar nuestro botón.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el método creado `getColorAzul(int color)`, realmente podrás pasarle cualquier color que tengas en los recursos, en Values/colors.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
private int fetchColor(@ColorRes int color) {
    return ContextCompat.getColor(this, color);
}

//USO:
fetchColor(R.color.colorModuloSDBottomActive)
```

Con ese metodo porporcionas un recurso (en este caso Color), y te devuelve el valor del Color.

Ojo tienes que declarar el color en los resources:

```
<color name="colorModuloSDBottomActive">#000000</color>
```

Saludos!